# Using Kinect for both navigation and user tracking

Tags: ros, navigation, kinect, ros-fuerte, tracking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'm trying to use one Kinect for two tasks: navigation and user tracking. At first firing navigation simultaneously with user_tracking doesn't work, and I couldn't find any information if anyone tried that?

Navigation and tracking work if I run them separately.

Any help would be appreciated!

da-na

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62896/using-kinect-for-both-navigation-and-user-tracking/) by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-05-16**:
Please be more specific as to "doesn't work". Also, what user_tracking package are you using?

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2014-12-04**:
I am working on the same type of project.  What packages are you using?

I am using [openni_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_camera)for the Kinect, [openni_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker) for skeleton tracking, and [p2os-vanderbilt](http://wiki.ros.org/p2os-vanderbilt) for Pioneer3DX.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2014-12-04**:
I have not yet started on the navigation piece yet, but I figure I would start with [this package](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation).  I figure the 'goal location' could subscribe to the tf topic of the skeleton with an offset.  I'll keep you posted with updates and you will see my questions soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS nodes are a publisher/subscriber system - the publishing nodes (should) operate normally no matter how many subscribers are consuming the data downstream. Are you pushing the limits of your hardware's processing capability?

Check `top` output to see the CPU load. An easy way to reduce processing load with Kinect or other RGBD cameras is to reduce the resolution using `dynamic_reconfigure`.

How are you using the Kinect output in navigation? Instead of using the pointcloud as a datasource, try feeding it through `pointcloud_to_laserscan` or use the depth image via `depthimage_to_laserscan`, both options will reduce the CPU load significantly.

Please add launch files and debug output to your question.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have gotten my robot to be able to navigate and user track.  I am utilizing ROS Hydro on two Ubuntu 12.04 computers.  One is the base computer.  The other is on my Pioneer3-DX with the Microsoft Kinect.  In order to do navigation and user-tracking, I run a launch file to start the following nodes: `p2os_driver`, `p2os_enableMotors`, `p2os_urdf`, `openni_launch`, `openni_tracker`, and `depthimage_to_laserscan`.

I then worked through the [Navigation Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials) and [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData), to learn to set up the appropriate navigation parameter files and how to use gmapping.  I then used the following `move_base.launch` file to start navigation and this [RViz Navigation Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack) to control the robot.

The robot is able to navigate while tracking users.

**It is possible to do both skeleton tracking and navigation using one Kinect.**  I am not sure what problems you are having.    As mentioned before, please post your launch files and any errors you have.  I will try to help you if I can.

---

**move_base.launch:**

```
<launch>

  <!-- Start gmapping -->
    <node  pkg="gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" output="screen" />

  <!-- Start navigation -->
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find follow_me_2dnav)/launch/costmap_common_params_p3dx.yaml" ns="global_costmap"/>
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find follow_me_2dnav)/launch/costmap_common_params_p3dx.yaml" ns="local_costmap"/>
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find follow_me_2dnav)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml"/>
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find follow_me_2dnav)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml"/>
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find follow_me_2dnav)/launch/base_local_planner_params.yaml"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1